# Hibernate 4.2.21 GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I'm working with Hibernate 4.2.21 Final, to generate the ID I use : **strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE**

```
@Id 
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ApplicationSequence", sequenceName =
"application_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ApplicationSequence")      
@Column(name = "application_id", unique = true, nullable = false) private Long id;
```

My question it's about Why Hibernate generate my ID's in a Random way ...

like 1, 2, 3, 67, 89, 96 etc...

When my allocationSize is = 1? should be something like: 1,2,3,4,5,6.

**EDIT:
SECUENCE IN ORACLE 12**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "OSYDBA"."APPLICATION_SEQ"  
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1
CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION ;
```

Comment: How have you generated the sequence on oracle side?

Comment: Yes, you can find it in my initial post, in EDIT

Comment: Are you using the same sequence for any other entity?

Comment: is it really a problem? this a a result of trade-off with performance requirements. You can not have concurrent, fast, gap-less sequence generator.

Comment: @ibre5041 If the same sequence is used by multiple entities, it is possible that rows inserted in a table may not be in sequence.

Comment: @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu and is it really a problem? sequences do guarantee only uniqueness. It is not a timestamp. Anyway on every concurrent database the order of inserts might be different from order commits. So for example when you "see" IDs: 10, 12, 20, 21. Then somehow magically row having ID=18 can appear in the database. You should never rely on IDs order.

Comment: @ibre5041 it is a problem perse. What i meant was, if we want to have **primary key column of a particular table to increment with no gaps** then sharing the same sequence across the tables doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't let Oracle precache any sequence value:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE APPLICATION_SEQ
      INCREMENT BY 1
      START WITH 1
      NOMAXVALUE
      NOCYCLE
      NOCACHE;
```

Comment: ah! ok, Thanks!! Can you explain me the resson ..Why not??

Comment: With sequence generator you are telling Hibernate to get from Oracle a valid sequence number, so Oracle will grab sequence numbers in blocks of 20 (your defined cache size) and then use an internal cache to return them.

Comment: The problem in the sequence is not only the cache, but even the NOORDER clause; for [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm): "Specify NOORDER if you do not want to guarantee sequence numbers are generated in order of request. This is the default."

Comment: @Aleksej Very true, I've missed the NOORDER in the posted sequence.

Comment: Why not you didn't put the <ORDER> clausule? It should be better no? Another important point it's "ORDER is necessary only to guarantee ordered generation if you are using Oracle Database with Real Application Clusters" we are in a Cluster App with two Node's..

Comment: @JOANA_Batista Just, curious, have you tried with this new version of the sequence? How was the output?